# I am trying to implement navigation drawer in kotlin but getting an error

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer

I am trying to implement android navigation drawer which is a part of navigation UI but while implementing it via kotlin i am getting an error that says unresolved error.

```
    class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

            val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph, drawerLayout)

            setContentView(R.layout.activityhome)

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using the `navigation-ui-ktx` dependency?

Comment: No, I am not using navigation-UI ktx dependency

Answer (score 2):

As per the [Navigation Declaring Dependencies documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#declaring_dependencies), the documentation assumes you are using the `-ktx` versions of the dependencies if you are writing in Kotlin.

The [`AppBarConfiguration(NavGraph, Drawerlayout)` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/ui/package-summary#appbarconfiguration) is a Kotlin extension available only in the `navigation-ui-ktx` dependency.

Answer (score 2):

We can use this instead of navigation UI if you don't want to use jetpack

```
    val drawwerlayout = drawer_layout
    val t = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawwerlayout,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close)
    drawwerlayout.addDrawerListener(t)
    t.syncState()

    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

    nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when(it.itemId)
        {
            R.id.logout -> {
                Snackbar.make(homeLayout,"Logged out Clicked", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        drawwerlayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        true
    }
```

Comment: No, you shouldn't do this if you're using Jetpack Navigation.

Comment: i am not using jetpack Navigation